# Ansible Playbook is it necessary to specify the exact version of the package to set on hold by dist-upgrade?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Ansible 2: Is it possible in Ansible Playbook to exclude a package that normally would be upgraded during dist-upgrade by using just the name of the package instead of the exact version?

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: yes
  tasks: 

  - name: disable upgrade of Java
    dpkg_selections:
      name: openjdk-8-jre
      selection: hold
```

I'd like to specify just `openjdk` instead of `openjkd-8-jre` because no openjdk should be installed no matter what version of openjdk is available to upgrade to (have different servers with different ubuntu os).

Comment: Did you tested a simple `name: openjdk-*`?

Comment: msg": "dpkg: error: illegal package name at line 1: illegal package name in specifier 'openjdk-*': character '*' not allowed (only letters, digits and characters '-+._')",

Comment: `openjdk-8-jre` **is** the name of the package. The version comes after (the latest on ubuntu bionic for example being `8u252-b09-1~18.04`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Preliminary note (extending my comment)

`openjdk-8-jre` **is** the package name. There is actually one different package for each major version of java. They can be installed alone or all together and managed through `alternatives`. But e.g. `openjdk-11-jre-headless` will never replace `openjdk-8-jre-headless`.

So it is quite unusual to hold such packages as your are cutting yourself off the latest bug and security fixes that should not impact the application using it (e.g. a `java-8` application should run on any minor version of `openjdk-8`).

That being said, if you still want to do it...

## Solution with `package_facts`.

This is basically doing exactly what you were trying except it will only mark as `hold` existing packages on the machine (which is probably better anyway).

Ansible has a [`package_facts` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/package_facts_module.html) which will return the existing installed package in the `packages` variable.

The idea: get those package name, select only the ones starting with a given name and feed that list to `dpkg_selections` to mark them as `hold`. The below playbook was tested successfully against my unbuntu 18.04 home machine.

```yaml
- name: Disable package upgrade based on partial name
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  become: true

  vars:
    partial_hold_name: openjdk
    partial_hold_regexp: "^{{ partial_hold_name }}.*"
    hold_package_list: "{{ packages | dict2items | map(attribute='key') | select('match', partial_hold_regexp) | list }}"

  tasks:
    - name: Gather package facts
      package_facts:

    - name: dselect all openjdk packages if they exists
      dpkg_selections:
        name: "{{ item }}"
        selection: hold
      loop: "{{ hold_package_list }}"
```

Which gives (first run with openjdk-11 and openjdk-8 installed in parallel and marked as "install")

```
$ ansible-playbook test.yml 

PLAY [Disable package upgrade based on partial name] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gather package facts] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [dselect all openjdk packages if they exists] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item=openjdk-11-jre-headless)
changed: [localhost] => (item=openjdk-8-jdk-headless)
changed: [localhost] => (item=openjdk-8-jre-headless)

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```